# Decision tree using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, decision-tree, visio

My Excel file contains a tree of the following type:

| id | question | parent id | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smth. | - |  |
| 2 | Smth. | 1 | No |
| 3 | Smth. | 1 | Yes |

How do I build this tree in Visio? I can't find a guide for creating and connecting shapes from VBA.

I have prepared a dictionary in which each vertex corresponds to a list of its children, because of my little experience in VBA, I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have any existing code to share (as text) in your question (assuming by 'dictionary' you mean a `Scripting.Dictionary`)?

Comment: _"I can't find a guide for creating and connecting shapes from VBA."_ - The Visio VBA reference for Shapes is right here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape - use a `Connect` object to connect `Shape` objects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.connect

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy text, English is not my native language. Yes, I meant `Scripting.Dictionary`. Unfortunately, I can't show a piece of code, since the working computer is protected and does not have access to the network. The scheme is something like this: I made the original ids the keys of the dictionary, and I made their values of the `Vairant()` type and put all the child vertices in them. I am not sure that this approach is successful, because I am more interested in reproducing the graphic tree in Visio, and not in the data structure of the VBA language